# Digital Signatures with PHP

Tags: php, cryptography, digital-signature

Is it possible to let users e-sign a document?

**Scenario**

1. I upload document for a user on my website to review and sign
2. User logs in, reviews the document and then somehow digitally signs it. ( not a image of their signature )
3. I receive document with some way of verifying they legally signed it.

I would prefer the user does not need to download, sign with some third party tool and then upload the document.  I want them to somehow perform this action on the webpage maybe by typing there full name in a box against the document while they are logged in.

Comment: *maybe by typing there full name in a box against the document while they are logged in.* - that does not sound like a legally binding kind of signature.

Comment: Not where I live (NL/Europe), you need to sign with a key on a CC-certified eID "smart card" handed over by the government. And that's just because they filled in the required laws for this. They did however not yet distribute any eID's for it...

Comment: truth. I was just saying maybe full name would be just a part in the validation process. I live in the US, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One feasible way would be to generate a [cryptographic pair of keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) for each and every user. Both keys (the private and the public one) would need to be kept on your server, with the private key being password protected. The password would ideally be known to only the user himself (ask for it when generating the keys but do NOT save it) and nobody else. Then, after the user has signed a document by entering his private key password you would be able to verify his "signature" using his public key.

The process itself greatly depends on your server setup (i.e. access to cryptographic tools, database and the like).

PS: I doubt this would be legally binding (at least not where I am located) but your jurisdiction may vary.

Comment: So for example I would have the user create a password solely for signing documents?  This password would be used for their private key so only they could technically "sign" the document.  Once the document is signed it is encrypted then we use the public key to decrypt it and  if it matches we are good? or did I get that completely wrong...

Comment: That basically sums the idea, yes.

Comment: one small question.  How would I know the document was signed with the private key and not the public key?  Or is the idea that I am holding onto the public key so no one else should have it?

Comment: No, you could post the public key on facebook and it wouldn't matter. Please read the linked Wikipedia article (especially the part about digital signatures). It says: "[...] is the use of asymmetric key algorithms, where the key used to encrypt a message is not the same as the key used to decrypt it." In your case (digital signature) the key used to encrypt is the private key, whereas the public key is used to verify the signature.

Comment: Besides, the encryption takes place on your server (you mentioned you don't want the user to fiddle with third party tools). So it's pretty much a no brainer: You encrypt with the user's password and private key - you decrypt with the user's public key. If the result is meaningful (an ID or any other arbitrary data you are encrypting) than you can be sure that the user has signed the document.

Answer (score 0):

"some way of verifying they legally signed it" .. has slightly different implications depending on the country (your profile does not indicate your location). I can only answer for the U.S. concerning the legal part .. but as for the technical part ..

You can use PHP to export each page of the PDF as a PNG, then present each page (as a PNG image) for the user to review. Then use JavaScript to record the user's action of signing at the specified location. The user then posts his/her acceptance of the signature and log it. When each user has "signed", you can make the document available for download. When the first user wants to download the PDF with all signatures, you can simply apply a signing cert verifying that you (your app/company) certify the authenticity of the document and the signatures, much the same way that a "public notary" notarizes a document. You will have to be able to provide a way for the document to be linked to the signing log for the signatures (when you logged the action of the user signing) and the authentication log when you authenticated the user. I use iText wrapped in a Java SOAP service for manipulating the PDF and then just have PHP call the service. I have created an app which does it this way but as of now it's still in alpha else I would link it.

dotloop has a simple approach similar to the above, minus real authentication and apparently their system is used successfully for thousands of real estate transactions (the escrow company will authenticate all parties to the transaction)

Note: app sign-on, or even OAuth is not as authentic as the European smart-cards but even those are not fool-proof. Perhaps a better solution for authentication would be to have the user upload a copy of their ID (AirBnB does this). Another solution might be to integrate a simple flash app to record the signer making a statement that they accept the signature for that transaction and link it to the doc and the signature.

The key things to remember are: (1) You can handle everything in the web-app stack (HTML; JavaScript; PHP; iText) so the user never has to download the actual PDF. (2) In many cases, as long as you can authenticate the user making the signing action for the document, only need to "certify" on the final document that the user did it and provide proof of that (like dotloop does) instead of certifying each signature. By certify, I mean, you sign the final PDF with an [AATL](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/approved-trust-list2.html) cert.

Comment: I developed a equal solution client PHP and Java iText server. Do you know how to sign with you private key in pure PHP the hash received back from iText ? I'm doing something wrong because after signed with openssl_sign() , the final PDF is getting corrupted. I read about openssl_pkcs7_sign() PKCS7 CMS content, but I can't find instructions how to create this envelope using PHP.

Comment: Sorry, I don't since I never tried it. Why does it need to be a pure PHP solution?

Comment: In fact the solution has two parts (Java server with iText and client in PHP). So I need to sign in PHP the hash sent back from Server Java iText. My hash signature is getting corrupted.